# No such entity with formCode = adminhtml_customer

Tags: magento2, error, customer

I am trying to add new customer from *admin panel* that shows an error:

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 1319656328

the error is `No such entity with formCode = adminhtml_customer`. Does anyone have solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your `customer_form_attribute` Table. check this table in your database. there is no data in `formCode` column related `adminhtml_customer`.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento1 you needed to tell magento exactly which form is allowed to save which customer attribute to the database.

This information is saved into `customer_form_attribute`

Not sure it changed in Magento2.